# ASP.NET Core application slow increase in CPU and memory without any requests

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application deployed to an Azure App Service (Windows).

The application has received 0 requests during the past ~48 hours, but the CPU, Memory and Handles are steadily increasing (see image) during this time.

I'm seeing this across multiple different App Services, but they are using some common startup logic, so I'm wondering if something in there is causing this, but I don't know how to debug it.

How can I debug what is going on? What kind of dump should I take or profiler should I use to understand what causes this? Any help would be great!

[image: Increasing CPU, Memory, Handles]

Comment: 1. Take memdump of problematic Azure process (Google for how) 2. Use windbg or ANTS Memory Profiler to analyze (again, Google will tell you how).

Comment: @IanKemp I'll do that, but do you think a memory leak could lead to increasing CPU usage as well? Because I guess that's what I could find by doing a memory dump right?

Comment: If we want to analysis the reason about why the CPU and memory usage is very high. We need to know what happened at that time. The dump could help us to find out the reason. This is why we need the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose CPU / Memory, you can try the built-in feature of azure web app(see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics#open-app-service-diagnostics)).

Nav to azure portal -> your azure web app -> in the left panel, click on `Diagnose and solve problems` -> click on `Proactive CPU Monitoring` / Momery respectively.